# Perl Threads::Queue

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm creating an array of Thread::Queue elements.
I'm doing that like this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $queues_amount; $i++){
    $queues[i]=Thread::Queue->new;
}
```

However, while I'm filling it each queue with elements like this

```
$queues[$index]->enqueue($element);
```

I get the following error :

**Can't call method "enqueue" on an undefined value...**

Could you help me with finding out what the problem is?

My perl version is 5.12.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using the `$` sigil on the `$i` variable within your loop:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $queues_amount; $i++){
    $queues[i]=Thread::Queue->new;  # should be $i
}
```

If you had `use strict` on, the `subs` portion would have thrown an error about the bareword `i`.  To catch many errors, place `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of all of your programs.

It is also a bit more idiomatic to write it as:

```
my @queues = map {Thread::Queue->new} 0 .. $queues_amount - 1;
```